# Every answer I gave on math stackexchange has downvotes, and I just joined. Is this typical for the site?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/181915/terrence-town

I guess I was wrong with some of my answers like the absolute value one but they seemed harsh.

Comment: May be you failed to follow the general advice of spending a couple of days (or a couple of hours at least) observing how the regulars behave? May be you just decided to crash the party? Anyway, it sounds like in your case the downvotes are a way of signalling a faux pas.

Answer (score 14):

The Math Stack Exchange is the one place you will find on the SE network that embraces partial answers, or "hints."  This is probably what happened to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964262) which, despite your "I think you can figure out the rest," essentially gives the OP the complete answer without giving him the opportunity to work through the problem himself.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/964252/3374) is a comment, not an answer. If you don't have enough reputation to comment, the correct response is to *refrain from commenting.*

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/964322/3374) doesn't explain anything.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/964315/3374) doesn't answer the question that was asked.  Again, you're trying to comment when you haven't earned the privilege to do so yet.

Comment: The first answer linked also introduces needless and irrelevant complexity to a very simple question.

Comment: So it does ....

Comment: I think in the first answer he was joking with OP, just read that question :))

Comment: Yeah, I didn't look at the question initially, only the answer.

Answer (score 7):

When I want to say something humorous, especially at a poor question, I generally leave a comment rather than an answer. People take answers a little more seriously, I suppose. Meanwhile, while comments cannot be downvoted, i do get some negative responses, in which case i usually delete the comment myself. Others are deleted by moderators; this has never happened when i was actually discussing mathematics, so i do not worry about it.

I have had answers that changed to non-mathematics after people insisted that I was wrong, some of those turned out very funny and I was sorry to see them deleted; for those with 10K [Is $1847^{2013}+2$ really a prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402357/is-184720132-really-a-prime)   I figure that is the deal, though, it is a mathematics website. The two comments that caused me to replace my answer with an admission of guilt were:

> I don't know. But I do know that 6575 is less than 7993 . (And it
>   always has been!) So "You have no way whatsoever" is patently false.

and then

> OK, I found this link which suggests that a number of this order of
>   magnitude can be proved prime by Primo on a top-end personal computer
>   in about 40 hours. So it really is time to recant, Will!

It was the word recant that did it.

Comment: "Others are deleted by moderators" Math.SE has moderators?

Comment: @Ampt, sure, you can click on Users and then on Moderators. If you work hard and keep your nose clean you can be a moderator too someday.

Comment: WillJagy: I'm sure that @Ampt is aware of this. But the moderators on programmers.SE are _far_ more active (or perhaps proactive) than would be remotely tolerated here, for better or worse. Consider some of the stats from [this MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237474/214632).

Comment: @ArthurFischer, right, my guess was that ampt was commenting on MSE moderators being less intrusive.

Comment: For what it's worth, that deleted answer made my day. :)  Sometimes I feel like there's an entire "secret sub-site" on StackExchange only for 10k+ users.